# AR.js Marker Not Training properly

Tags: javascript, ar.js

I have this custom logo where it creates the .patt file which is not working properly is there any design rules for AR.js

Is there any problem with the custom marker I have followed the design principles

https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/three.js/examples/marker-training/examples/generator.html

I have this image

[image]

How can I get the exact .patt file

Comment: Also, try to insert within square images like having high resolution at least 512x512px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that the background should be rgb(240,240,240) and you should have an eye on the grid which is going to be produced. As you can see from the produced .patt file there are 16 values per row so if you have an image which is hitting that grid well then you're more likely to get a good recognition result.

[pattern screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8eSV.png)

[Marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp5Un.png)

Comment: I have seen the forum where they are talking about can you please tell me if you find anything similar to the vuforia like capability with AR.js